# Defining Lookup Data in Bootstrap Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am Using Bootstrap Autocomplete in HTML form. 
In that, I have Successfully Fetched the Data Using Ajax.
In Ajax Success, I have to Get the Data and the I use Bootstrap Autocomplete In success response.

This is the Data I get in the Ajax Success.

```
var ajaxResponseData = [{data: "1", value: "Tom Smith"},
                        {data: "2", value: "Tommy Smith"},
                        {data: "3", value: "add Smith"}];
```

Now the Ajax & Autocomplete Script.

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: get_industry_type,
         success: function (response) {

            var ajaxResponseData = '['+ response +']'; // I got Data Here

 // Here is the Bootstrap Autocomplete. 
              $('.functional_area_data').autocomplete({

                    lookup: ajaxResponseData, //Problem is here. I did not get the Data here. 
                    appendTo: '.functional_area_div',
                    minChars: 1,
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {

                        var selectedValueID = suggestion.data;

                        $(this).closest('.functional_area_div').find('input[name="functional_area_id_hidden[]"]').val(selectedValueID);
                    },
                    onInvalidateSelection: function (value) {

                        $('#candidata_exp_form input[name="functional_area_id_hidden[]"]').val('');
                    },
                    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
                    noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results'
                });

         },
         error: function(e) {         
            console.log(e);
       }
      });
```

The Main Trouble is that Bootstrap Autocomplete is not getting Ajax response data inside the autocomplete. How Do I get that Data?

Comment: What if You Declare the Variable Statically in Ajax success? Did Your Autocomplete work properly?

Comment: Yes, I Have Done that and that will run smooth. Only Problem is that the autocomplete is not get that ajax response.  Any suggestion??

Comment: Can you Help Me over this @TomasKirda